# VueJS Firebase Syntax error

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuejs2, firebase-authentication

I cannot find the syntax error in this signup method. It's been more than an hour now.

```
.then(() => {
            db.collection("users").doc(this.slug).get().then((doc) => {

                let data = doc.data()
                db.collection("users").doc(cred.user.uid).set(data).then({
                  db.collection("users").doc(this.slug).delete()
                })

            })
          })
```

This code above basically gets the newly created document, then puts the data into `let data`. After that, it creates a new document with the User UID as the name passes the data to it and then just deletes the old document. A syntax error lies in that code, but the indicator says, it is the dot between db and collection (db.collection)

[Error report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LyyX.png)

```js
methods: {
    signup(){
      console.log('signup ran')
      if(this.heroName){
        this.slug = slugify(this.heroName, {
          replacement: '-',
          remove: /[$*_+~.()'"!\-:@]/g,
          lower: true
        })
        console.log(this.slug)
        let ref = db.collection('users').doc(this.slug)
        ref.get().then(doc => {
          if(doc.exists){
            this.feedback = 'This alias already exists'
          } else {
            // this alias does not yet exists in the db
            this.feedback = 'This alias is free to use'
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
            .then(cred => {
              ref.set({
                alias: this.heroName,
                user_id: cred.user.uid,
                gemcount: 15
              })
              // FIXME: error below
              .then(() => {
                db.collection("users").doc(this.slug).get().then((doc) => {

                    let data = doc.data()
                    db.collection("users").doc(cred.user.uid).set(data).then({
                      db.collection("users").doc(this.slug).delete()
                    })

                })
              })
              .then(() => {
                this.$router.push({ name: 'Core' })
              })
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err)
              this.feedback = err.message;
            })
          }
        })
      } else {
        this.feedback = 'Please enter a heroName'
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection("users").doc(cred.user.uid).set(data).then({
     db.collection("users").doc(this.slug).delete()
})
```

`then` expect its parameter to be a function, I reckon it where your error come from, the correct should be:

```
db.collection("users").doc(cred.user.uid).set(data).then(() => {
     db.collection("users").doc(this.slug).delete()
})
```